# Setting cumulative values to constant after it reaches threshold

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a pandas time series which contains cumulative monthly values.

If in a month on a certain date, the value becomes a certain number, I need to set rest of the days to 1000.

E.g.

```
df:

 Date       cummulative_value
1/8/2017    -3
1/9/2017    -6
1/10/2017   -72
1/11/2017   500
1/26/2017   575
2/7/2017    -5
2/14/2017   -6
2/21/2017   -6
```

My cutoff value is -71 so in above example I need to achieve the following:

```
 Date       cummulative_value
1/8/2017    -3
1/9/2017    -6
1/10/2017   1000
1/11/2017   1000
1/26/2017   1000
2/7/2017    -5
2/14/2017   -6
2/21/2017   -6
```

I am trying to leverage `groupby` in pandas but I am not sure how to go about it. Any other more efficient way will help also.

Comment: Not it doesn't account for which month cumulative value is in

Comment: Is there a cutoff value per month?

Comment: -71 is cutoff for each month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `cumprod`:

```
df['cummulative_value'] = (df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m'))['cummulative_value']
                            .transform(lambda x: np.where(x.ge(-71).cumprod(),x,1000)))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        Date  cummulative_value
0 2017-01-08                 -3
1 2017-01-09                 -6
2 2017-01-10               1000
3 2017-01-11               1000
4 2017-01-26               1000
5 2017-02-07                 -5
6 2017-02-14                 -6
7 2017-02-21                 -6
```

Comment: I would have never been able to reach your solution .. I need to even learn what "transform" and "gt" are .. thanks

Comment: Basically, you group by month using the string format of the date to YYYYMM, then you can your cum_value into 1 and 0 for each value greater than or equal to (ge) -71, Once a value is zero leave it zero.  cumprod is good for this.  and lastly, use np.where like an if then statement, if 1 then return cum_val else return constant value.

Comment: How would I modify the code if I wanted the cutoff to be active on 2017-01-11. i.e. let the first one to meet condition stay

Comment: I don't see any cumsum() in your answer?

Comment: @Zanam sorry cumprod()

Comment: It doesn't work .. if you consider this example 1/8/2017    -3
1/9/2017    -6
1/10/2017   -72
1/11/2017   500
1/26/2017   75

Comment: @Zanam Mind starting a new question with new data and new expected data?

Comment: Yes ..I was thinking the same

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that involves creating a mask:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%m/%d/%Y"), inplace=True)

mask = df['cummulative_value'].lt(-71).groupby(df.index.month).cumsum()

# Date
# 2017-01-08    False
# 2017-01-09    False
# 2017-01-10     True
# 2017-01-11     True
# 2017-01-26     True
# 2017-02-07    False
# 2017-02-14    False
# 2017-02-21    False

df.loc[mask, 'cummulative_value'] = 1000

df.reset_index(drop=True)

#         Date  cummulative_value
# 0   1/8/2017                 -3
# 1   1/9/2017                 -6
# 2  1/10/2017               1000
# 3  1/11/2017               1000
# 4  1/26/2017               1000
# 5   2/7/2017                 -5
# 6  2/14/2017                 -6
# 7  2/21/2017                 -6
```

Comment: I am not able to make your solution run. It errors out at the third line after 'mask'

Comment: @Zanam I just ran it again on the sample df from scratch (on python 3.6.2 with pandas 0.20.3) and didn't encounter an error. Please feel free to let me know what the error is if you'd like me to take a closer look.