# Setting cumulative values to constant after it reaches threshold and preserving first value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas time series which contains cumulative monthly values.

If in a month on a certain date, the value is less than a certain number, I keep the first one and set everything through rest of month to 1000.

E.g.

```
df:

 Date       cummulative_value
1/8/2017    -3
1/9/2017    -6
1/10/2017   -72
1/11/2017   500
1/26/2017   575
2/7/2017    -5
2/14/2017   -6
2/21/2017   -6
```

My cutoff value is -71 so in above example I need to achieve the following:

```
 Date       cummulative_value
1/8/2017    -3
1/9/2017    -6
1/10/2017   -72
1/11/2017   1000
1/26/2017   1000
2/7/2017    -5
2/14/2017   -6
2/21/2017   -6
```

On `1/10/2017   -72` the cumulative value was lower than -71 so we keep it but every value for rest of Jan 2017 is now set to 1000.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48571951/setting-cumulative-values-to-constant-after-it-reaches-threshold) sets all values to 1000 when condition is met. I need to keep the first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels a bit hacky....  I am not proud of it.  But it make work for your dataset.

```
df['cummulative_value'] = (df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m'))['cummulative_value']
                            .transform(lambda x: np.where(x.ge(-71).cumprod()
                            .shift(1).fillna(1),x,1000)))
```

Output:

```
        Date  cummulative_value
0 2017-01-08                 -3
1 2017-01-09                 -6
2 2017-01-10                -72
3 2017-01-11               1000
4 2017-01-26               1000
5 2017-02-07                 -5
6 2017-02-14                 -6
7 2017-02-21                 -6
```

Comment: Beautiful .. I love reading your answers. I was using a for loop and this is so much smarter approach